# SQL Server NEWID() using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: sql, hibernate

Is it possible to use the function `NEWID()` with hibernate/jpa ?

I would like to order by `NEWID()` using the CriteriaBuilder however I cannot find anything in the documentation on how to use this function within the `CriteriaBuilder.orderBy();` function. Or is there some other way to get a random result from the query using the CriteriaBuilder?

I am using the following dialect; `SQLServer2012Dialect`